# How to evaluate $\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{z} e^{-\left(\frac{z-1}{b}\right)^{\frac{1}{a}}} dz$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I am really stuck on this integral:

\begin{equation}
\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{z} e^{-\left(\frac{z-1}{b}\right)^{\frac{1}{a}}} dz
\end{equation}
where $a,b$ are real constants.

Is it a special integral? Is there a closed form for this? Now, I am trying to expand in a taylor series but I don't have a good result. Any advice?

Comment: This will most likely involve the [Exponential Integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral), which is not an elementary function.

Comment: Duplicate of [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1280617) and [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1277343).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to evaluate the integral $\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{a-1}}{1+bx^a} e^{-x} dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1280617/how-to-evaluate-the-integral-int-0-infty-fracxa-11bxa-e-x-dx)