# How to simplify this special case of Meijer G-Function?

Tags: special-functions, contour-integration, mellin-transform

I have the following expression, involving the Meijer G-Function:

> $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{a} (2 \pi)^{(a-1)/2}} G_{1,a+1}^{a+1,1}\left( \frac{c^a}{a^a} \left|\begin{matrix}0\\
> 0,0,\frac{1}{a},\frac{2}{a},\dots,\frac{a-1}{a}\end{matrix}\right.\right)$$

Here $a \in \mathbb{N},~c>0$.

I believe this can be simplified, using the misterious 'duplication formula' from [this paper, top of page 3](http://cybertester.com/data/issac97.pdf).

It's really too long to type so I'll reproduce the relevant parts of the paper on this screenshot:

[image]

> As you can see this looks exactly like my case. I would really like your help in figuring out how to simplify my expression so it looks like the left hand side in the Theorem above.

---

**Edit**

Also from Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meijer_G-function#Basic_properties_of_the_G-function

$$\delta =m+n-{\tfrac {1}{2}}(p+q)$$

$$\nu =\sum _{j=1}^{q}b_{j}-\sum _{j=1}^{p}a_{j}$$

$$G_{p,q}^{\,m,n}\!\left(\left.{\begin{matrix}\mathbf {a_{p}} \\\mathbf {b_{q}} \end{matrix}}\;\right|\,z\right)={\frac {h^{1+\nu +(p-q)/2}}{(2\pi )^{(h-1)\delta }}}\; \times \\ \times G_{hp,\,hq}^{\,hm,\,hn}\!\left(\left.{\begin{matrix}a_{1}/h,\dots ,(a_{1}+h-1)/h,\dots ,a_{p}/h,\dots ,(a_{p}+h-1)/h\\b_{1}/h,\dots ,(b_{1}+h-1)/h,\dots ,b_{q}/h,\dots ,(b_{q}+h-1)/h\end{matrix}}\;\right|\,{\frac {z^{h}}{h^{h(q-p)}}}\right)$$

$$\quad h\in \mathbb {N}$$

This seems to be more clear, I'll get some sleep and figure it out.